# How to properly import tsv to athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am following this example:

[LazySimpleSerDe for CSV, TSV, and Custom-Delimited Files - TSV example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html#tsv-example)

Summary of the code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE flight_delays_tsv (
 yr INT,
 quarter INT,
 month INT, 
    ...
 div5longestgtime INT,
 div5wheelsoff STRING,
 div5tailnum STRING
)
 PARTITIONED BY (year STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 LOCATION 's3://athena-examples-myregion/flight/tsv/';
```

My questions are:

- My tsv does not have column names

(my tsv)
[image]

Is it ok if I just list the columns as c1,c2… and all of them as `string` ?

- I do not understand this:

  PARTITIONED BY (year STRING)

in the example, the column ‘year’ is not listed in any of the columns…

Answer (score 0):

**Column names**

The column names are defined by the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` command. I recommend you name them something useful so that it is easier to write queries. The column names do not need to match any names in the actual file. (It does not interpret header rows.)

**Partitioning**

From [Partitioning Data - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html):

> To create a table with partitions, you must define it during the CREATE TABLE statement. Use PARTITIONED BY to define the keys by which to partition data.

The field used to partition the data is *NOT* stored in the files themselves, which is why they are not in the table definition. Rather, the column value is **stored in the name of the directory**.

This might seem strange (storing values in a directory name!) but actually makes sense because it avoids situations where an incorrect value is stored in a folder. For example, if there is a `year=2018` folder, what happens if a file contains a column where the year is `2017`? This is avoided by storing the `year` in the directory name, such that any files within that directory are assigned the value denoted in the directory name.

Queries can still use `WHERE year = 2018` even though it isn't listed as an actual column.

See also: [LanguageManual DDL - Apache Hive - Apache Software Foundation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterPartition)

The other neat thing is that data can be updated by simply moving a file to a different directory. In this example, it would change the `year` value as a result of being in a different directory.

Yes, it's strange, but the trick is to stop thinking of it like a normal database and appreciate the freedom that it offers. For example, appending new data is as simple as dropping a file into a directory. No loading required!

Comment: Great detailed explanation. My concern now is… I know nothing about the data… I want to import it first and play a lil bit with it, to get to know it… (I mean, as of now, not even the columns have a name…) .  Can I do :

Create external table col1, col2, col3   PARTITIONED BY (xyz STRING). (using all fake names for columns and even for the partition?) can I even import it removing the ‘partitioned by’ clause? .   (after I play around with the data I think of doing a proper partitioning).

Comment: No need to do partitioning to start with, since it is merely a way of improving queries, but you don't yet know how you'll be querying the data. You might want to start by loading a subset of the data to get a feel for it -- or even just load some of it into Excel and play with it there, since it is more visual. Once you know your data better, you'll be able to organise it according to how you'll use it.

Comment: Thanks, if I decide to partition let's by year, do I need to create before a folder in my bucket named "year"?

Comment: I was doing partitioned by xyz, coz' I didnt care, i just wanted to play with the data... and when trying to query I got 0 results... now I removed the partition line and works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I think I don't understand what partitioning is? I have this .tsv file, do I first need to phisically partition it? can one .tsv file be partitioned? or partitioned means that there are several files in the folder?

Comment: If you have a single input file, then you have no need for partitioning. Partitioning is a method of creating a hierarchy of directories, each of which can contain multiple files. When data is queried, the system is smart enough only to look in directories that contain the desired value (eg `year=2018`). This is totally irrelevant if you only have one file, or just a few files. It's only useful when you have thousands of files and GBs of data.